# create SQL insert script, Returns: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python

I have the below dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vin': ['test'], 'modelId':['5641'], 'year': ['2021'] })
```

I am trying to create an SQL insert script from it using the below function..

```
import pandas as pd
    def createSqlInsertStatement():
        global sql_texts,row
        sql_texts = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+ ' registry'+' (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year)' 
            + ' VALUES "MANUAL_LOAD", sysdate, 42, 0, "MITSUBISHI", '+ ',' + str(tuple(row.values))) +';'
            return sql_texts
```

But I keep getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Desktop\testsql.py in <module>
----> 1 createSqlInsertStatement()

c:\Users\Desktop\testsql.py in createSqlInsertStatement()
      9     sql_texts = []
     10     for index, row in df.iterrows():
---> 11         sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+ ' registry'+' (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year)' 
     12         + ' VALUES "MANUAL_LOAD", sysdate, 42, 0, "MITSUBISHI", '+ ',' + str(tuple(row.values))) +';'
     13         return sql_texts

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I need ...

```
INSERT INTO registry (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year) VALUES ('MANUAL_LOAD', sysdate, 42, 0, 'MITSUBISHI', '5641', '2021');
```

Im going insane and looking for a none type that I cant find, or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: try instead of the `+` the `and`

Comment: Why are you adding/concatenating string literals in the first place? It seems like this can much better be done using a single [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error at the end of your append statement:  `+';'` should be inside the parenthesis for "append". Right now you are trying to concatenate the result of "append" with a string(character) `';'`.

Correct it to be:

```py
sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+ ' registry'+' (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year)' 
            + ' VALUES "MANUAL_LOAD", sysdate, 42, 0, "MITSUBISHI", '+ ',' + str(tuple(row.values)) +';')
```

EDIT: Apart from correcting the syntax error above, I believe your code will not give you the output you are looking for as you are not looking to add the tuple to your string. This statement might be cleaner ([using `format` function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) instead of `+`)

```py
sql_texts.append("INSERT INTO registry (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year) VALUES (\"MANUAL_LOAD\", sysdate, 42, 0, \"MITSUBISHI\", \"{0}\", \"{1}\");".format(row.values[1], row.values[2]))
```

This gives the output as:

```
['INSERT INTO registry (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year) VALUES ("MANUAL_LOAD", sysdate, 42, 0, "MITSUBISHI", "5641", "2021");']
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you missed the closing parenthesis for `sql_text.append` and put an extra parenthesis in `str`

Try this It will return an array with query

```
import pandas as pd
    def createSqlInsertStatement():
        global sql_texts,row
        sql_texts = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+ ' registry'+' (source, create_time, geo_group_id, status, make, vin, modelId, year)' 
            + ' VALUES "MANUAL_LOAD", sysdate, 42, 0, "MITSUBISHI", '+ ',' + str(tuple(row.values)) +';')
            return sql_texts
```